# How to populate a ComboBox depending on the selected item from another ComboBox in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I have tables inside my MySql database:

1. material
2. unitofmeasure

I also have 2 comboboxes:

1. cmbHeader - this combobox populates the tables inside the database.
2. cmbContent - this combobox SHOULD populate the columns inside the table selected from cmbHeader

I was able to populate the cmbHeader with the tables inside my database using this code:

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=NewPass;database=converter"
    Try
        conn.Open()
        dt = conn.GetSchema("TABLES")

        cmbHeader.DataSource = dt
        cmbHeader.DisplayMember = "table_name"
        cmbHeader.ValueMember = "table_name"

        command.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Now for the cmbContent, I get an error in my code. I use this code:

```
Private Sub cmbHeader_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbHeader.SelectedIndexChanged, cmbList.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=NewPass;database=converter"

    conn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM '" & cmbHeader.SelectedItem & "'"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    reader = command.ExecuteReader

    cmbList.Items.Clear()

    While reader.Read
        Dim header = reader.GetString("Header")
        Dim content = reader.GetString("Content")
        Dim convert = reader.GetString("Convert")

        cmbList.Items.Add(content)
    End While

    command.Dispose()
    reader.Close()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

This is the image of the error that I get using the code above.
[image: Error1]

I tried changing my query to "SELECT * FROM '" & cmbHeader.SelectedItem.ToString & "'" but I get a different error. How can I populate my 2nd ComboBox depending on what I choose on my 1st ComboBox? Please help I'm stuck. Thanks. :)

Comment: how can you use single qoutes for table name? and also you are taking selecteditem from combobox instead take selectedvalue or selectedtext.

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line in your code,

```
query = "SELECT * FROM '" & cmbHeader.SelectedItem & "'"
```

with this line,

```
query = "SELECT * FROM " & cmbHeader.SelectedItem.Value & ";"
```

Hope this will work.
Thank you.

Comment: This didn't work sir. It still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

make your query as like this:

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM " & cmbHeader.Text '<-- updation
                            OR
 query = "SELECT * FROM " & cmbHeader.SelectedValue '<-- updation
```

but it is not a good practice as it lead to [sql injection](http://amolnaik4.blogspot.in/2012/02/sql-injection-in-insert-query.html) so i suggest you to do it using parametrized(*in this case injuction can be avoided as it allows only selected values from the combo box. but in general it is not a good practice that's why am suggesting like this*) query as like the following

```
    query = "SELECT * FROM ?"
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand 
    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = query
        .Connection = con
        .Parameters.Add(New OdbcParameter(@table,cmbHeader.SelectedItem ))
     End With
```

Comment: try the updation which i had posted

Comment: It still shows the same error as before. I think the problem is on the syntax of my query? It reads the & which should just be a concatenation. Is there any other way to write my query to make it work?

Comment: try using parametrized query

Answer (score -1):

**FOR OTHER PEOPLE WHO HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM**

I was able to figure out what's wrong with my code. The value of the combobox I'm getting returns "Data.Row.DataRowView" that's why my query fails. I changed this:

```
cmbHeader.DataSource = dt
cmbHeader.DisplayMember = "table_name"
cmbHeader.ValueMember = "table_name"
```

into this:

```
cmbHeader.ValueMember = "table_name"
cmbHeader.DisplayMember = "table_name"
cmbHeader.DataSource = dt
```

Then on my SelectedIndexChanged event, I used this:

```
Dim value As String = ""
    value = Convert.ToString(cmbHeader.Text)

    conn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM " & value
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    'With command
    '    .Parameters.AddWithValue("header", value)
    'End With

    reader = command.ExecuteReader

    cmbList.Items.Clear()

    While reader.Read
        Dim content = reader.GetString("Content")

        cmbList.Items.Add(content)
    End While

    command.Dispose()
    reader.Close()
    conn.Close()
```

Hope this helps. Thanks for the help everyone. :)